# Javascript error Comparing strings

Tags: javascript

I have problem comparing two strings coming from a list and an array.

List:

```
 <label>Εδρα-Νομός
 <select name="Edra_nomos" size="1" id="Edra_nomos">
     <option value=" Επιλογές"> Επιλογές</option>
     <option value="Αιτωλοακαρνανίας"> Αιτωλοακαρνανίας</option>
   ..........................................................
```

2D array:

```
var edra = [['Αιτωλοακαρνανίας','Αγρινιο','Ναυπακτος','Μεσολόγγι','Βόνιτσα','Αμφιλοχία'],
     ['Αργολίδας','Αργος','Κρανίδι','Ναύπλιο','Τολό','Επίδαυρος']];
```

Javascript part:

```
var s = $( "#Edra_nomos option:selected" ).text();      

if( s==edra[0][0]){
    alert('1');
} else{
    alert('0');
}
```

When I select first option from list (`Αιτωλοακαρνανίας`), alert box gives me 0. Why?

Comment: use trim() as the option text has a space - `$( "#Edra_nomos option:selected" ).text().trim()`

Comment: Or use `$( "#Edra_nomos option:selected" ).val()`

Comment: @Tushar your answer would work for the second option, but not the first where the value includes a space `" Επιλογές"`